# Delete last occurrence of a comma in a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to delete the last occurence of a comma in the following string:

**52 Tex. 641, 100 S.W.3d 276, 60 Tex. 472, 65 Tex. 723, 10 S.W.3d 34,**

Any ideas on how to do this via Javascript? Maybe with Regex perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Try `.lastIndexOf()`.

```
var s = '52 Tex. 641, 100 S.W.3d 276, 60 Tex. 472, 65 Tex. 723, 10 S.W.3d 34,';
s = s.substr(0, s.lastIndexOf(','));

console.log(s);
// 52 Tex. 641, 100 S.W.3d 276, 60 Tex. 472, 65 Tex. 723, 10 S.W.3d 34
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`"52 Tex. 641, 100 S.W.3d 276, 60 Tex. 472, 65 Tex. 723, 10 S.W.3d 34,".replace(/,$/, "");`
```

Explanation:

> `,` matches the character , literally
>
> `$` assert position at end of the string

```js
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "52 Tex. 641, 100 S.W.3d 276, 60 Tex. 472, 65 Tex. 723, 10 S.W.3d 34,".replace(/,$/, "");
```

```html
<span id='test'></span>
```

---

Or, just remove the last character of the string if the comma will always be the last character of the string:

`"52 Tex. 641, 100 S.W.3d 276, 60 Tex. 472, 65 Tex. 723, 10 S.W.3d 34,".slice(0, -1);`

```js
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "52 Tex. 641, 100 S.W.3d 276, 60 Tex. 472, 65 Tex. 723, 10 S.W.3d 34,".slice(0, -1);
```

```html
<span id='test'></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last letter in a String:

```
var hello = "hello"
hello = hello.substring(0, hello.length - 1)
// hello is now 'hell'
```

or in your case

```
var comma = "1231, 12313, asdfasdf,"
comma = comma.substring(0, comma.length - 1)
// comma is now '1231, 12313, asdfasdf'
```